# How to do customer Lat-Long place search in radius using google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-app-engine

I have set of previously obtained latitude & longitude using GIS application for various places.
What i have to do is... I want to show these obtained lat-long on map as marker from my current location to certain radius.

Say if my current location is -33.8665433, 151.1956316 and radius 1000 then I want to show all obtained lat-long as marker falling in this range.

This : https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search helps for specific defined place type. I don't have predefined type.

How to solve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with geo-queries on AppEngine is that datastore [limits inequality queries to at most one property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Inequality_filters_are_limited_to_at_most_one_property). I.e. you can not perform an inequality query on both lat and lon , which basically limits the geo-proximity queries.

The solution is to [geo-hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) your data: break the map into discrete grid and give each quadrant an ID. Then also mark all places with the appropriate quadrant ID.

An example of [geo-hash on AppEngine](http://hitching.net/2009/11/10/scalable-fast-accurate-geo-apps-using-google-app-engine-geohash-faultline-correction/). There is also a java library that performs geo-hashing on AppEngine: https://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/