# Finding a nearest location by using Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have stored latitude and longitude values in my object in Objectify (Google App Engine), but I don't know how to find a nearest location in Objectify.

I found a sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/GeoPoint) but I'm also looking for tips.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303582/how-to-do-customer-lat-long-place-search-in-radius-using-google-map-api/25305325#25305325

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about Geospatial Queries which are yet not supported by the Google Cloud Datastore. This feature is still in alpha stadium. Please see the following post for this topic

[Geospatial Query at Google App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705870/geospatial-query-at-google-app-engine-datastore)

So you need to implement your logic. A possible solution would be to use Geohashes e.g.

https://github.com/davidmoten/geo

Comment: dont find sample with latude and longtude junit test from your git

Comment: this is not my Git and the JavaDocs are available and I can see a lot of Unit Tests e.g. https://github.com/davidmoten/geo/blob/master/geo/src/test/java/com/github/davidmoten/geo/GeoHashTest.java